# Google Cloud Tasks: Location 'europe-west1' is not a valid location

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I am trying to run a Google Cloud Tasks task using a Cloud Function, but I'm hitting an error where any region I try to use is wrong.

The code is basic. All is well until it stops because of the following error:

> Error: {"code":3,"message":"Location '**europe-west1' is not a valid location**. Use ListLocations to list valid locations.","details":[]}

If I attempt to use, for example, us-central1, it will report:

> Error: {"code":3,"message":"**Location must equal europe-west1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in europe-west1**","details":[]}

I am using the Google Cloud Tasks API with Node.js for creating a new Task:

```
const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true }); 
const parent = client.queuePath(PROJECT, 'europe-west1', QUEUE);
```

A full example can be found here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/blob/master/samples/createHttpTaskWithToken.js

The URL called is:
""https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com:443/$rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.CloudTasks/CreateTask"

If I run the locations list command, this is the output:

```
$ gcloud tasks locations list
europe-west1    projects/[project-id]/locations/europe-west1
```

Edit: Using the REST API (https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks/create) with the same configuration works. It may be a bug in the client?

I am really not sure what is wrong with my setup.

Not sure what information would be helpful to debug this, so apologies in advance if there's not enough information.

Comment: What is the command that generates the error message? If the command requiring a Region or a Zone?

Comment: Hi John,


I am using the Google Cloud Tasks API for creating a new Task:


```
const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true });
const parent = client.queuePath(PROJECT, 'europe-west1', QUEUE);
```


The URL called is :"https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com:443/$rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.CloudTasks/CreateTask


From what I can see, the argument name is "location". If I run the locations list command, this is the output:


▶ gcloud tasks locations list                 
NAME          FULL_NAME
europe-west1  projects/[project-id]/locations/europe-west1

Comment: Do not post comments. Edit your question and include more information.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you need to specify the region as `projects/[project-id]/locations/europe-west1`

Comment: I tried `europe-west` too, but returns the same error. I think the client will build that URL with the information passed through the SDK, but I can try execute a manual call with that

Comment: @user1886812 did you ever figure this out? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I realized which the example that you are using is for non App Engine/Cloud functions environments please try the simple example that is in the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/tasks).

Please check on your package.json that you are defining the latest version of google-cloud/tasks library, at this time it is 1.9.0

You don't need to use a Ouath token within App Engine/ Cloud Functions environments, because are already configured with a service account.

```
// Imports the Google Cloud Tasks library.
  const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');

  // Instantiates a client.
  const client = new CloudTasksClient();

  // TODO(developer): Uncomment these lines and replace with your values.
  // const project = 'my-project-id';
  // const queue = 'my-appengine-queue';
  // const location = 'us-central1';
  // const payload = 'hello';

  // Construct the fully qualified queue name.
  const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

  const task = {
    appEngineHttpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      relativeUri: '/log_payload',
    },
  };

  if (payload) {
    task.appEngineHttpRequest.body = Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64');
  }

  if (inSeconds) {
    task.scheduleTime = {
      seconds: inSeconds + Date.now() / 1000,
    };
  }

  const request = {
    parent: parent,
    task: task,
  };

  console.log('Sending task:');
  console.log(task);
  // Send create task request.
  const [response] = await client.createTask(request);
  const name = response.name;
  console.log(`Created task ${name}`);
```