# INVALID_ARGUMENT: Location 'europe-west1' is not a valid location

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

My error code after calling the below (which is shortened for brevity) within a cloud functions is:

`Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Location 'europe-west1' is not a valid location. Use ListLocations to list valid locations.`

If I change to location to "us-central" for example, the error code changes to:

`Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Location must equal europe-west1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in europe-west1`

I have had a look on stackoverflow for similar but came up short. I left a comment on this question to see if the op had any luck:

[Google Cloud Tasks: Location 'europe-west1' is not a valid location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930970/google-cloud-tasks-location-europe-west1-is-not-a-valid-location)

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

JT

OS: Google Cloud Functions
Node.js version: 12
npm version: 6.14.10
@google-cloud/tasks version: 2.3.0

Steps to reproduce

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {CloudTasksClient} = require("@google-cloud/tasks");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true });

// Omit the actual triggered function

async function createHttpTasks(session) {
  const project = "XXXXX"; // These match my project and queue id/name
  const queue = "XXXXXX";
  const location = "europe-west1";
  
  // Construct the fully qualified queue name.
  const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);
  
  // Do stuff
  
  const requestCheck = {parent, taskCheckIn};
  await client.createTask(requestCheck);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had two things wrong:

```
const client = new CloudTasksClient({ fallback: true });
```

should have been:

```
const client = new CloudTasksClient();
```

and

```
const requestCheck = {parent, taskCheckIn};
```

should have been

```
const requestCheck = {parent, task: taskCheckIn};
```

thanks to the gcloud team for responding to my issue:

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/issues/509

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is getting this error, make sure there are no spaces in the location variable. For example, there is a space at the end of the variable:

`location="europe-west-3 "`